# How do you force a nested first menu item with MvcSiteMapProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

My project requires the first element of their menu to have 3 nested elements:

```
L1_Heading1 ------------------ L1_Link1--------------------L1_link2
  |
  |----L2 Link1
  |----L2 Link2
  |----L2 Link3
```

I am trying to use the MVCSitemapProvider, but I cannot figure out how to make the first menu item nested...
Here's an example Site

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="false">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" description="Home">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Home" action="Dashboard" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="My Profile" controller="Profile" action="MyProfile" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="My Jobs" controller="Profile" action="MyJobs" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Workplace" controller="Workplace" action="Index" description="users">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Calendar" controller="Workplace" action="Calendar" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customers" controller="Workplace" action="Customers" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Equipment" controller="Workplace" action="Equipment" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

This unfortunately causes a duplicate of the node home ([Reference](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/02/10/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial/))...
[image: :]

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `startingNodeInChildLevel` argument of the `Menu` HTML helper to `false`. There are several overloads that have this parameter, but this is the simplest:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(startFromCurrentNode: false, startingNodeInChildLevel: false, showStartingNode: true)
```

On a side note, *never* duplicate nodes in the SiteMap. The matching behavior requires each node to have a unique set of route values or a unique URL.